# Tkinter escape button command, how to create it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How would one go about adding a command to the escape button (X at top right) that also throws a yes/no messagebox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you create a reference to `Tk()`, e.g. `root`, you can use the [protocol `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#protocols) to bind a callback to the escape button as you say.

This could look like:

```
import tkMessageBox

...

def callback():
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really wish to quit?"):
        root.destroy()

...

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", callback)

...
```

(Example taken from ['**Capturing destroy events**'](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm#protocols))